# WPBakery Page Builder Shortcode Showing On Front Page For Post

Tags: plugins, excerpt

I am working on a new site and am having an issue with the WPBakery plugin. I assume its a custom version of WPBakery, since it's marked WPBakery Page Builder by VisualModo, which is who my theme is through.

The problem I am having is tat on the front page, which is static, I have a section to show Blog items and they do show up, along with the short codes that are rendered correctly on that actual post. I am trying to figure out how to filter our the shortcodes only when showing the excerpt of the post on the front page.

Here is a sample of what the excerpt looks like

[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]I am text block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]

Answer (score 1):

Chris, you need to:

1 - Go to Posts and edit a Single Post

2 - Then go to "Screen Options" (top right of the screen) and make sure that "Excerpt" is checked

[image]

3 -  Scroll down and you'll see a new field "Excerpt", enter whatever you want to appear as the excerpt of the post.

[image]